# Linq to SQL: select additional count

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql

I want to select everything from a table but add an additional column holding a count() of other rows in another table. How can I do that? The groupby is not what I'm looking for I think. What I want to do in SQL:

```
Select *,(select count(*) from tableName2 where y=1) as count
from tableName where x = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
Context.TableName.Where(y>y.Column.Equals(1))
.Select(x=>new{Object=x,Count = Context.TableName2.Count()})
```

Will generate this:

```
Select *, (select count(*) from TableName2)
from TableName
Where TableName.y = 1
```

Comment: But this is not the same, it will count ALL rows in tablename2 no matter the selected x

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is

```
from r in context.tablename
where r.Column == 1
select new { y, y.Tablename2.Count() }
```

But even without the explicit select you can Always use the count..

```
var r = context.tablename.Single(s=>s.column == 1);
```

And futher on you can use

```
r.Tablename2.Count()
```

Depending on your datacontext settings this will lead to an extra SQL statement so the first is more efficient